# Multivariate integration of a derivative w.r.t. a single variable

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$x=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$. If $\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_{l}}=f(x_{l})$
for $l=1,...,n$, should we have $$g(x)=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\int f(x_{l})dx_{l}+c\ ?$$

If yes, what's the theorem or proposition behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. It looks better in vector notation: if $\nabla g = \mathbf F$, then $g(\mathbf r) = \int^{\mathbf r} \mathbf F(\mathbf r')\cdot \mathbf {dr'}+c$. This is known as the [fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_theorem).

---

Answering follow-up question:

> How can $g(x)=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\int f(x_{l})dx_{l}+c$ 
>   correspond to  $g(\mathbf r) = \int^{\mathbf r} \mathbf F(\mathbf r')\cdot \mathbf {dr'}+c$ ?

The first integral is what you get by writing out the dot product in the second integral in coordinates.