# True rigorous meaning of dx symbol in general?

Tags: integration, derivatives

From [Multivariate integration of a derivative w.r.t. a single variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/769155/multivariate-integration-of-a-derivative-w-r-t-a-single-variable), from words_that_end_in_GRY's answer.

From elementary calculus, I always thought $\int^{}$ and $dx$ were just a kind of "command" button to integrate something between the two, rather than a genuine mathematical object.

(I don't mean this is widely accepted definition of the terms, but by "mathematical object" I mean anything that can be subject to mathematical operation. By "command button" I mean symbol for operation of some kind. In "2+2=4" 2 and 4 will be mathematical objects and + and = will be command button.)

That understanding caused no trouble in elementary calculus like

$\int^{} \mathbf f(x) \mathbf {dx}$.

But it starts to confuse me when things like

$g(\mathbf r) = \int^{\mathbf r} \mathbf F(\mathbf r')\cdot \mathbf {dr'}+c$.

comes up. dot product! $dr'$ is being dot producted! Then clearly it sounds like $$dr'$ is some genuine mathematical object.

I remember I felt similar confusion in differential equation course and many others.

In short, what's the true rigorous meaning of dx symbol in general (possibly multivariate) setting?

Answer (score 1):

You want to learn about differential forms. You can start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form), but eventually you'll want to read some books.